# Problem sending password with spring boot via email

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So, I'm working on a web application using angular on the frontend, JWT tokens, and Spring Boot microservices on the backend, after adding the client by an Admin an email is sent to the client containing username and password! The problem is I got the username but the password that I got is encrypted!
So how can I send a decrypted password?

---

The email contains :

Your account has been created successfully

Username: PabloWarn
Password: $2a$10$YAmPGfRWG3ckI51P4gi8OuQ9nOEw045XfBio8f8Y9jkAIytuUppIe

Comment: One of the basic concepts of password security is that you, as the site owner, do not know what is the password. You only know the hash value of the password.

Comment: You don’t. Passwords should be stored using a 1-way cryptographic hash. Typical practice is to send them a link to a page where they can reset their password.

Comment: Ok thanks but sending them a link to a page where they can reset their password.should i reset the Token too ? cause i tried to do it but it didnt work for me ! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403483/spring-security-reset-password-with-sending-email-using-jwt

The problem is with the Token

Comment: If you are storing the tokens then just marked them as invalid or if you are not, then you can logout the user when he sends a request to reset the password.